# Trouble understanding how to pass a variable to a function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm simply trying to find the workbook beginning with D and containing the sheet "Bob".

This is my code, but it doesn't like wb.Name when I call the function. What am I supposed to put there so it works?

```
Sub View_Email()

'Select report workbook D*
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb1.Name Like "D*" And WorksheetExists("Bob", wb.Name) Then
            Ct = Ct + 1
            wb1.Activate
            Set WB_rep = ActiveWorkbook
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb1
    If Ct = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not find D* file (report). Code will end."
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Copy Burn-Down chart from report


End Sub


Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: The 2nd argument passed to `WorksheetExists()` must be a Workbook but you pass `wb.Name` which is a string, just pass `wb` on its own.

Comment: I tried that, but then it says Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: Not your current issue, but what is `wb1`?  Is that defined elsewhere in the code?

Comment: I think it might be because you haven't defined `wb` so it's a variant.  At the top of the code, but after Sub header type `Dim wb As Workbook`.

Comment: You also need to change `Next wb1` to `Next wb` - the loop uses `wb`.

Comment: You can also remove `wb.Activate` and `Set WB_rep = ActiveWorkbook` - replace with `Set WB_rep = wb`.  The book doesn't need to be active for you to set a reference to it.

Comment: I'd also go into Tools ~ Options and tick **Require Variable Declaration**.  This will put [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) at the top of each new module you create forcing you to declare your variables.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help. The following code is working now:

```
Sub View_Email()

Dim wb As Workbook

'Select report workbook D*
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "D*" And WorksheetExists("Bob", wb) Then
            Ct = Ct + 1
            wb.Activate
            Set WB_rep = ActiveWorkbook
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb
    If Ct = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not find D* file (report). Code will end."
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Copy Burn-Down chart from report


End Sub


Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```